# Symfony: Make internal file public

Tags: symfony, web, public, assetic

I'm having a file inside `Resources/views/somedir/somefile.js`. This file will not be used the static way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somedir/somefile.js"></script>
```

instead it will only be used inside another JavaScript-file. It will load it via AJAX. This file however is included with the above solution. But of course, the file it will try to load (`somefile.js`) is not yet in the web-directory.

Is there a way to make files as "public", without copy them to the web-directory manually?

Many thanks.

Comment: I think for that to be possible would mess you up when going live. Basically web is your root when on a serve so www.whatever.com/anything is your web dir, if you wanted to link to something in resources the way you say then all links would have to be www.whatever.com/web/anything or www.whatever.com/resources/jsfile.js however I think 'symlink' is designed for this purpose.

Comment: I think I miss understood your question could this bundlebhttps://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle be of help to you

Comment: Hi Doug, thank you for your reply. Well the bundle is not what I am searching for, but the symlink however is. I could create a folder inside the web-directory and set a link to the real folder inside Bundle/Resources/views/somedir/. But that has some problems: all files in the folder are public and you have to create the folder with the symlink manually.. So if there is no better option I will take this, but is there no option to make files public without linking to them in the HTML with assetic? For example say: make this file public, but don't create a `<script>`-tag, just make it public??

Answer (score 0):

Place files to  public directory

```
Resources/public/js/somefile.js
```

Then use asset tag

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/js/somefile.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: This is a problem because I can't use filters on it.